# How to make two pixel width splitter in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable

I'm developing a simple Android application that would have an action bar on the top of the screen:

[image]

I already have the bar with the gradient background (drawable) and the arrow icon set but I'm not sure how to create that two pixel width splitter.

The color of the left column of pixels is `#5e5e5e` and the right one is `#181818`.

What is the best way (optimized for performance) to create such a reusable splitter?

The best would be to make this splitter as a widget.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

The bar is a `LinearLayout` with a gradient background and the arrow is a single transparent `ImageView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a 2x1 pixel PNG image and use it as a background of a View widget:

```
<View 
     android:layout_width="2px"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/splitter" 
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use right margin on the left column. Or left margin on the right column. No need for a dedicated splitter view.

If you absolutely need the splitter to be a view, use `View`. You can give it a background and a size, that should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, but could figure out how a simple margin could make this 'splitter effect'. Can you please provide some example code? Also see my updated question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the look and feel of the two pixel width drawable.

Comment: You mean the light line/dark line combination? Use a 2px wide View with a 1x2 background image. Can't do that with a margin - the margin only makes the background of the underlying view shine through.